# Java regex. Match any "value" that is no preceded by given string

Tags: java, regex

I need some help with a **Java regexp**.
I'm working with a file that has **JSON** similar format:

```
['zul.wgt.Label','f6DQof',{sclass:'class',style:'font-weight: bold;',prolog:' ',value:'xxxx'},{},[]], 
['zul.wgt.Label','f6DQpf',{sclass:'class notranslate',style:'font-weight: bold;',prolog:' ',value:'xxxx'},
['zul.wgt.Label','f6DQof',{sclass:'class',style:'font-weight: bold;',prolog:' ',label:'xxxx'},{},[]]
['zul.wgt.Label','f6DQof',{sclass:'class',style:'font-weight: bold;',prolog:' ',label:'xxxx'},{},[]]
```

I need to match any `label` or `value` data that is not preceded by a "**notranslate**" value on the `sclass` property.

I've been working on an almost working **Regexp** but I need the final push to match only what I've previously wrote

```
((?!.*?notranslate)sclass:'[\w\s]+'.*?)((value|label):'(.*?)')
```

Right now it matches anything from `sclass` that it's not followed by `'notranslate'`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why not use some sort of JSON parser like GSON or Jackson, then check if property `sclass` contains `notranslate` etc

Comment: @Mark that is not valid json, wouldnt parsing that throw an Exception? The keys are not marked with double quotes.

Comment: I second Mark's comment - it seems you get a json object so treat it like that. Assuming `notranslate` is a property it could appear anywhere in the JSON so you'd have a hard time comming up with a reasonable regex.

Comment: @f1sh if you allow unquoted property names (Jackson has a feature for this) you should be able parse this as json - it looks like an array of arrays that contain strings, objects and further arrays. The only thing that might be needed (and I'd assume that's missing due to it being an example) would be the brackets for the outer array (Jackson and other parsers might be able to handle that as well).

Comment: How about `(?!notranslate).+(value|label):'([^}]+)'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of your current regex are in the 4th capturing group

You could also use 1 capturing group instead of 4:

```
^(?!.*\bsclass:'[^']*\bnotranslate\b[^']*').*\b(?:label|value):'([^']+)'
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/90QmA3/1)

That would match:

- `^` Assert start of the string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead to assert that what is on the right does not

  - `.*\bsclass:` Match any character 0+ times followed by `class:`
  - `'[^']*\bnotranslate\b[^']*'` Match `notranslate` between single quotes and word boundaries
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `.*` match any character 0+ times
- `\b(?:label|value):` Match either label or value followed by `:`
- `'([^']+)'` Match `'`, capture in a group matching not `'` 1+ times and match `'`

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/Gn1TlZ)